# jquery .remove is coming back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page set up with the jquery datatable UI.
in my html table I have a row like this:

```
<tr id="row1"><td>618408</td><td>1992</td></tr>
```

In my code I have this

```
$("tr #row1").remove();
```

when the script runs, my row gets removed and doesn't show.

If I go into the search box connected to the datatable for 1992, then my row magically reapers.

How else can I get the row to not show up again?

Comment: Should be `$("tr#row1")` or just `$("#row1")` probably, but it's hard to say without seeing more context.

Comment: The issue is because you're just removing the element from the UI. As soon as DataTables refreshes the content from the data source the row is added again. You need to either amend the data provided to DataTables before displaying it, or remove the row from your data store, depending on how permanent you want the removal to be

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other JS libraries other than JQuery and datatables (like an MVC / MVVM framework)?  Some piece of code other than what you've posted is affecting your DOM and restoring the object visibility.  I would start removing front-end code until that behavior ceases, then try to find a workaround.